# Convergence in probability of $n \cdot \min _{1 \leq j \leq n} X_j$?

Tags: probability, distributions, convergence, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \ldots \sim U(0,1)$ and $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$, and $X_1,X_2, \dots , X$ are independent. Does it follow that $n \cdot \min _{1 \leq j \leq n} X_j \stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} X$, for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: There should be a general result (not exactly in the same form) if you tone down to convergence in distribution. But whether it is affirmative for convergence in probability needs to be checked. What have you tried?

Comment: @jbowman what I wanted to seek is OP's attempt to try the given problem. I am not saying anything about convergence aside from a general result that might exist for weak convergence. OP knows what is convergence in probability. Can they apply the definition here? Why did they think so? That was what I sought. Clarification from op.

Comment: @User1865345 - fair point!

Comment: @User1865345 I have indeed proven that it converges in distribution, for which a trick was needed, namely that $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n \rightarrow e^{-x}$. I feel that proving this result from the definition would similarly require a trick of some kind, which I'm completely stuck on, nor do I see a way to use the convergence in distribution ... had it converged in distribution to a constant, that would have been sufficient, but here it does not.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Remember what convergence in probability is... let's assume you are actually AT the limit with the sequence.  Will the limit have converged in probability to the (completely unrelated) Exponential variate?